# Umlaut in windows path (æ, ø, å, ä, ...)

Tags: python, character-encoding, filepath

I try to access a path on Windows network drive. E.g. `z:\\ascii_name\non_ascii_name`, or with such an umlaut it would be `z:\\folder\folder with æ`.

os.path.join returns `z:\\\\folder\\folder with æ`, but I get a FileNotFoundError.
I'm running this using Anaconda3 on Windows 10. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns 'utf-8'.

I found some Python2 related threads that didn't get me any further. I would be very grateful for help and ideas.

Comment: Unicode ("non-ascii") filenames work fine *if* your Python source code encoding is set correctly. Make sure you're actually saving your `.py` files as Unicode (e.g. UTF-8). Check the settings of your text editor or IDE.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33858512/18771

Comment: æ and ø are not really "umlauts." The linguistic term refers to a systematic sound change like "tragen > trägt" (which to some degree does occur in Danish and Norwegian, too) but in a typographic context it usually refers to the trema / diaeresis diacritic.